# Filter Access form by multiple filters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that filters a database using multiple filters. However all filters need to be entered in or have a value for the table to be filtered correctly.

I would like to be that not all inputs are required to filter the table. 
I'm not sure if thats worded correctly.

[image]

Please see what I have tried so far.

```
 DoCmd.ApplyFilter _
 "select * from SageOrderLine_Live where " & _
 "[PromisedDeliveryDate] = " & Format(Me.DateFrom, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " 
 and " & _
 "[CustomerAccountNumber] = """ & Me.CustomerAccountNumber & """" & " and 
 " & _
 "[Code] = """ & Me.Codes & """" & " and " & _
 "[AnalysisCode1] = """ & Me.Analysis & """" & " Or " & _
 "[AnalysisCode2] = """ & Me.Analysis & """" & " Or " & _
 "[AnalysisCode3] = """ & Me.Analysis & """"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a parameterized query avoiding concatenation and quote punctuation by directly referencing form controls. Use such a query in form RecordSource calling `NZ` to assign missing search parameters to column itself. Logically this will render all search parameters optional. Do note below does not considsr `NULL` values.

**SQL** *(save as stored query object to be used as form's RecordSource)*

```sql
SELECT * FROM SageOrderLine_Live 
WHERE [PromisedDeliveryDate] = NZ(Forms!myform!DateFrom, [PromisedDeliveryDate])
AND [CustomerAccountNumber] = NZ(Forms!myform!CustomerAccountNumber, [CustomerAccountNumber])
AND [Code] = NZ(Forms!myform!Codes, [Code]) 
AND [AnalysisCode1] = NZ(Forms!myform!Analysis, [AnalysisCode1])
AND [AnalysisCode2] = NZ(Forms!myform!Analysis, [AnalysisCode2])
AND [AnalysisCode3] = NZ(Forms!myform!Analysis, [AnalysisCode3])
```

**VBA**

```vb
Me.Form.Requery
```